# How to save index and rating values both?

Tags: ios, swift

Here I had used `HCSStarRatingview` for rating and here i had implemented it in table view so that i need to get the selected particular rating value and need to save according to its index and there should be also in need to change the saved value later also and need to insert in the selected index can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ratingCell", for: indexPath) as! ratingCell
            return cell
        }
        else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewCell", for: indexPath) as! AddaReviewTableViewCell
            let arr = reviewModel[indexPath.row]
            cell.reviewTypeLabel.text = arr.ratingCode
            cell.starRatingControl.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.starRatingControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControlAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
        else{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reviewInputCell", for: indexPath) as! reviewInputCell
            nickName = cell.nameTextField.text
            summary = cell.summaryTextField.text
            review = cell.reviewTextView.text
            cell.submitReviewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submitReviewAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }
    }
    func isValidFirstname(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        let firstnameRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
        let firstnameTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", firstnameRegEx)
        let result = firstnameTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
        return result
    }
    func RatingControlAction(_ sender:Any){
        let buttonPosition = (sender as AnyObject).convert(CGPoint(), to: tableDetails)
        let index = tableDetails.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        print(String(format: "Changed rating to %.1f", (sender as AnyObject as! CVarArg)))
    }
```

And screenshot for this is shown here

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a struct which can hold two values

Declare a struct

```
struct Struct_Row_Rating {
var row: String
var rating: Int

    init(row: String , rating: Int ) {
    self.row = row
    self.rating = rating

}}
```

Declare an array

```
     var arrayAdaptor  = [Struct_Row_Rating]()
```

Append array like this

```
  arrayAdaptor.append(Struct_Row_Rating(row: IndexPath.row, rating: 3)
```

You can retrieve the value by

```
var index1 = arrayAdaptor[1].rating // use dynamic value here
```

[More on struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Update it as your requirments bro..Declare it as Int if u need it that way